# cannot Load URL with android

Tags: android, android-networking, android-internet

I want check for update of app; I use this function but it doesn't work and go to catch in first and second try. what is the problem of this ?

you can see some log of it when want to download the page :

http://pasteboard.co/hn2hx7t.png

```
void CheckForUpdate()
        {
            handler.post(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {

                    try
                    {
                        URL versionURL = new URL("http://sth.com/daycounter/moharam_day_counter.php?p=widget_version_code");
                        URL widgetURL = new URL("http://sth.com/daycounter/moharam_day_counter.php?p=widget_url");
                        URLConnection urlConnection = versionURL.openConnection();

                        BufferedReader bufferReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader( urlConnection.getInputStream()));

                        String version = bufferReader.readLine();
                        Log.i("WP", ""+version);

                        if(Integer.parseInt(version) >= Integer.parseInt(versionCode))
                        {

                            bufferReader.close();
                            urlConnection = widgetURL.openConnection();
                            bufferReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream()));
                            String widgetURLString = bufferReader.readLine();
                            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(widgetURLString));
                            ShowNotifyCation("", "***", intent, 1, R.drawable.icon_image, R.raw.alarm_sound);

                        }
                        bufferReader.close();
                    }
                    catch(Exception e)
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    if(!GetIsShowBeheshtNote())
                    {
                        try
                        {


                                URL beheshtIsCommingURL = new URL("http://http://sth.com/daycounter/moharam_day_counter.php?p=behesht_is_coming");
                                URL beheshtURL = new URL("http://sth.com/daycounter/moharam_day_counter.php?p=behesht_url");                
                                BufferedReader bufferReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(beheshtIsCommingURL.openStream()));
                                String isComing = bufferReader.readLine();
                                if(Boolean.parseBoolean(isComing))
                                {
                                    bufferReader.close();
                                    bufferReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(beheshtURL.openStream()));
                                    String beheshtURLString = bufferReader.readLine();
                                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(beheshtURLString));
                                    ShowNotifyCation("", ******", intent, 2, R.drawable.icon_image, R.raw.alarm_sound);
                                    SetIsShowBeheshtNote();


                                }
                                bufferReader.close();
                        }   
                        catch(Exception e)
                        {

                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are making network requests on main thread. Main thread is dedicated to UI operations, so android enforces you to use AsynTasks or Threads.

Create a new AsyncTask and add your download logic to `doInBackground` method and use the result in `onPostExecute`

Example from google:
http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/connecting.html

```
private class DownloadWebpageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {

        // params comes from the execute() call: params[0] is the url.
        try {
            return downloadUrl(urls[0]);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return "Unable to retrieve web page. URL may be invalid.";
        }
    }
    // onPostExecute displays the results of the AsyncTask.
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        textView.setText(result);
   }
}
```